# Counting column value 4 joins in

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a database with several tables. I'm trying to create a view that will take a column from the top-level table and a count function from the final table that requires 4 joins.

This is what I have.

```
  ClassData            SubclassData                FCStackData         
id || name           id || name || class_id       id || name || sc_id
 1 || class one       1 || sc1  || 2               1 || s1   || 2
 2 || class two       2 || sc2  || 2               2 || s2   || 2


FlashcardData                         ScoreData
id||word || def || fcstack_id          id || correct || fcd_id
1 || w1  || d1  || 2                    1 || true    || 2
2 || w2  || d2  || 2                    2 || true    || 2
```

Okay, so I need to select ClassData.name -- and then I need a column called Correct that checks ScoreData and returns me the number of times each distinct class comes up with a true value.

So in my basic tables above, I want my query to return this:

```
      Class Name     ||  Correct
      class one      || null        <-- no corresponding data in scoredata
      class two      || 2           <-- both columns in scoredata are for this
```

Here's my query which I realize is pretty wrong but I'm not sure how to even tackle this.

```
    SELECT ClassData.name as ClassName,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ScoreData.correct 
= 'true' THEN 1 END) AS Correct
FROM ((((ClassData
INNER JOIN SubclassData ON ClassData.id = SubclassData.class_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN FCStackData ON SubclassData.id = FCStackData.subclass_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN FlashcardData ON FCStackData.id = FlashcardData.fcstack_id)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN ScoreData ON FlashcardData.id = ScoreData.fcdata_id)
GROUP BY ClassData.name
```

Note: I simplified the tables and query a bit, just taking out data that doesn't matter for this problem.

So what I'm actually getting from this query is only my first ClassData.name item and the Count column as 1 (I only have one entry in the actual DB).

Comment: Why are you using a right outer (as opposed to left outer) join on ScoreData?

Comment: Honestly I was just trying to change the 4 joins, using as many combinations as I could just to see what would happen. This just happens to be the last one I stopped at.

Comment: For what it's worth...  A inner join B means "give me all of the rows from table A where there is at least one corresponding row from B", A left outer join B means "give me all the rows from A, matched with rows from B if any exist, and for any cases where more than one row from B that match duplicate the rows from A", and A right outer join B means the opposite of left outer join (all the rows from B, regardless of whether A exists). So you probably want all left outer joins.

Comment: You are correct, could have sworn I tried all left outer joins. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you just want `left join`s through the query:

```
SELECT cd.name as ClassName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN sd.correct = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Correct
FROM ClassData cd LEFT  JOIN
     SubclassData scd
     ON cd.id = scd.class_id LEFT JOIN
     FCStackData fsd
     ON scd.id = fsd.subclass_id LEFT JOIN
     FlashcardData fcd
     ON fsd.id = fcd.fcstack_id LEFT JOIN
     ScoreData sd
     ON fcd.id = sd.fcdata_id
GROUP BY cd.name;
```

Comment: Could have sworn I tried that, because I did read up on the different joins to check where I was going wrong...but yes, you are correct! Thanks!